# PHP - search on query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select query from database. if I write this code :

```
$selectOption = $_GET['name'];
echo $selectOption.'<br>';
$sql = "SELECT 'rpm' FROM sn WHERE power = '1s1s'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "rpm: " . $row["rpm"];
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

It shows me correct answer. Otherwise , if I write this :

```
$sql = "SELECT 'rpm' FROM 'sn' WHERE 'power' = '$selectOption'";
```

It shows me *0 results*. any suggestion to correct above query?

Comment: Use backticks (`) for field name not single quotes.

Comment: What does `$selectOption` holds?

Comment: better still don't use single quotes or tilde characters around field names. the single quote turns the column name into a string, the tilde or backslash is not standard sql, and is not necessary unless you've used a reserved word as a column name. Best practice in that case is to rename the column.

Comment: maybe you don't have any data stored in database for the value of `$selectOption`

Comment: That second query (with the variable in it) is wide open to SQL-injection, see [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should use prepared statements, *specially* when you're bringing variables in from `$_GET`

Comment: $sql = "SELECT `rpm` FROM `sn` WHERE `power` = '$selectOption'"; use (backticks)

Comment: *"It shows me correct answer"* - and using `$sql = "SELECT 'rpm' FROM sn WHERE power = '1s1s'";`? I find that rather hard to believe. Not with those quotes `'` it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things, both are stated in comments:-

1.Use backticks(`) in your query like this:-

```
 $sql = "SELECT `rpm` FROM `sn` WHERE `power` = '$selectOption'";
```

2.Prevent your query from SQL Injection. For that use prepared statement. Link is given in comment section. For your help i put it in my answer :- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: so, you discarded my edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34558431/2 and your point #1 doesn't show as it "should"; as "code".

Comment: No i didn't discarded. Meanwhile i also edited and i  think because of that discard happen